# How to extract specific text from a multiple records text file?

Tags: bash, search, text, extract, text-extraction

I have a text file with the following structure:

```
Record 1
property1: some_number1
property2: some_number2
property3: some_number3
...
property20: some_number

Record 2
property1: some_other_number1
property2: some_other_number2
property3: some_other_number3
...
property20: some_other_number
...
...
...
Record 350
property1: more_numbers1
property2: more_numbers2
property3: more_numbers3
...
property20: some_other_number
```

(here `...` represents more properties/records)

Using a bash script, I want to input the Record number, and then extract some specific property values to a `.csv` file. For example, using `2` (for Record #2) and the `propery2`, results in `some_other_number2`:

```
Record, property2
2,some_other_number2
```

I already tried read the file line by line, and keep checking if a given string (ex. Record 2) is found and then look for a line with property2, unsuccessfully.

Comment: Have you tried using `awk`? When the record number matches, set a variable. Then when the property matches and the variable is set, return that value.

Comment: No, I have no clue about using awk.

Comment: The structure in bash should be similar. Read the file line by line. If it matches `Record $N`, set a variable. If the variable is set and it matches `propertyX:`, extract the value and break out of the loop.

Comment: You said you tried to implement it. Show what you tried and we'll help you fix it. We won't write it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If your txt file is formatted always in that way, you might not even need awk.
You can simply grep for the option number you want, right after the record number you want.

For example this function will write what you want in a cvs file:

```
function extract_property {
nrec=$1
nprop=$2

prop=$(echo $(cat test) | grep -Po "Record $nrec .*?property$nprop:[\s\t]*\K[^\s\t]*")

cat > extracted.csv <<EOF
Record, property$nprop
$nprop, $prop
EOF
}
```

For example:

```
extract_property 2 2
```

writes the file

```
Record, property2
2, some_other_number2
```